# Soft 404 errors in webmaster tools for a wordpress blog

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm getting errors in Webmaster Tools lately that seem to come from the plugin "Flare" I've used that look like this:

"The target URL doesn't exist, but your server is not returning a 404 (file not found) error." (in the smartphone tab)

URL:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flare_get_counts&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2my-article-name%2F&post_id=125&_wpnonce=0a98274b5d
```

When I click on this url, it only say "0". Before I turned the plugin off it said "[]" (without quotes).

It says that it's linked from:

```
http://example.com/my-article-name/
http://example.com/my-article-name/?replytocom=17910
http://example.com/my-article-name/?replytocom=3518
```

I've deleted that plugin "Flare", but the errors still seem to be coming in.

Why I look at the source code of for any of the pages above I cannot see anything about "flare".

What can I do?

Thanks,
Eddie

Comment: 2 Up votes, but no comments or answers in nearly 2 years? What's going on here? Did this ever get resolved Eddie?